# Fast way to generate sequences for RNN/LSTM Model from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe which includes 200k+ unique IDs and for each ID 33 time periods with numeric data as well as padded values to ensure same sequence length for my RNN model. The data is sorted already by ID and time. Overall, the pandas dataframe has just over 8M rows! I'm generating the np array sequences currently, but it takes so long (code below).

I'm wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way to generate them. I'll share a data sample below as well as my current code. Thank you in advance and let me know if there are any follow up questions!

```
# pandas dataframe example
id  time    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 y
a1  1       161 11  137 15  386 15  275 10  422 1   344 3   18  0
a1  2       487 14  77  11  329 7   188 12  174 2   462 14  14  0
a1  3       92  2   12  11  226 20  50  5   313 9   65  19  13  0
…   …       …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …
a1  31      434 6   30  12  216 12  151 18  470 20  414 4   13  0
a1  32      271 2   456 12  100 19  198 12  377 14  205 13  1   0
a1  33      183 15  34  10  499 20  229 6   191 20  145 13  2   0
a2  1       247 10  54  6   115 14  102 9   39  6   34  1   8   0
a2  2       216 19  423 4   205 13  458 12  226 7   264 18  6   0
a2  3       311 7   285 5   147 6   30  17  332 10  116 13  1   0
…   …       …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …
a2  31      124 13  62  11  229 4   242 20  261 6   350 16  8   0
a2  32      359 9   290 2   72  14  478 2   197 14  188 7   11  0
a2  33      410 15  370 18  34  9   387 5   218 9   257 5   1   1
```

```
# current sequence generation code
def create_sequence_data(df, num_features=num_features, y_label='y'):
    
    id_list = df['id'].unique()
    
    x_sequence = []
    y_local = []
    ids = []

    for idx in id_list:

        x_sequence.append(df[df['id'] == idx][num_features].values.tolist())

        y_local.append(df[df['id'] == idx][y_label].max())
        ids.append(idx)

    return x_sequence, y_local, ids


x_seq, y_vals, idx_ls = create_sequence_data(df=df, y_label='y')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution actually worked fast enough for me. In the code prior to the one above I was also looping through rows for each `id` but the filter on `id` alone and then the `values.tolist()` call outputs a list of lists perfect for the sequence modeling.

In terms of time by total rows in the several dataframes was just over 8M and I was able to get through each one in under a couple hours so not too bad compared to before.